# Excel substitute function match entire cell contents

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a `VLOOKUP` function that was returning a `0` instead of blanks when there was no match.

```
      A               B
1   Heading     Heading
2   Data A      The year is 2015
3   Data B            0
```

To combat this I used the `substitute` function:

```
=IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(VLOOKUP($A2, 'HC Total'!A:C, 3), "0", ""), "")
```

Which overall solves the issue, however if the `VLOOKUP` value contains a `0` anywhere it is replaced. For example `The year is 2015` becomes `The year is 215`.

I would like to avoid using:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A2, 'HC Total'!A:C, 3)=0, "", VLOOKUP($A2, 'HC Total'!A:C, 3))
```

As I don't want to call `VLOOKUP` twice if it can be helped.

Is is possible to use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to match and replace entire cells containing `0`, not any occurrence of `0`?

Comment: Is `0` one of the values in column C? I can't reproduce VLOOKUP returning `0` when no match is found. Also, B540Glenn is absolutely right that you must include that last `FALSE` argument in your VLOOKUP if you're looking for an exact match.

Comment: This is the first time I have experienced `VLOOKUP` returning `0`. The `0` just crops up in column C every now and then in normal text, as per the example provided. The `VLOOKUP` sits in a table, and the `VLOOKUP table_array` is an array formula, so maybe some odd combination of these are causing the `0`, as all cells have general formatting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Vlookup() call `VLOOKUP($A2, 'HC Total'!A:C, 3)` is missing the Range Lookup parameter.  When this parameter is omitted, it will default to True.  This will tell the function to find the closest match, assuming the data is sorted ascending.

Try using:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2, 'HC Total'!A:C, 3,False), "")
```

The Vlookup() will return a #N/A if the value in not found and the IfError() will replace it with a blank.

EDIT:  In response to your comment

I will assume the values you wish to return are integers that can contain a zero but will be larger than the single 0 returned by the Vlookup().

To get around this, use the IFERROR(VLOOKUP()) combination and use a custom format for your destination cell 

`0;-0;;@`

If your values contain decimals, then use

`0.00;-0.00;;@`

Comment: Tried this already, excel always returns 0 instead of #N/A, hence this work around.

Comment: The look up values are mostly text that can contain numbers, such as `The year is 2015`, but the custom formatting is working with the `IFERROR(VLOOKUP())` method thank you.